# Restful API in Php?

Tags: php, rest, http-get

I want to make restful API in php,i have a file 'index.php' in which php and html code is there,i am trying to make api for it. So please suggest me is it right way to do?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$verb=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($verb == 'GET')
{
if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
$response = file_get_contents($_GET['filename']);
echo $response;
}
else{
die("ERROR: REQUIRED PARAMETERS NOT GIVEN!");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it with a framework (eg. Laravel, Lumen, etc.)?

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-rest-api-with-lumen/

Comment: is it wrong? its also working but javascript code is not working that is in index.php.

Comment: Read Dmitry Kiselef reply   :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to determine your API endpoints paths and verbs, like:

```
GET /file/{filename} - will get a file
POST /file - will create a file
```

Second, you shouldn't use `$_GET['filename']`, since your endpoint is for example `GET /file/myfile.txt`, where filename parameter is `myfile.txt` and this is a part of the path. So you have to extract parameters from the path.

Third, it's better to use microframework for that purpose.

Comment: like i don't have much time so i am using this,can you tell me how to extract parameter from the path.suggest me what changes i have to make in my code.